# Difference between "have had" and "having"

Tags: differences, present-perfect, present-tense, progressive-aspect

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> - I have had a headache since this morning.
> - I am having a headache since this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I've had a headache since `past.time.point`* is normal, idiomatic, and grammatical.

**I'm having a headache since `past.time.point`*, however, is ungrammatical,
because the present progressive construction (*'m having*) refers to the present moment,
while the prepositional phrase (*since `past.time.point`*) refers to a length of time in the past,
starting at `past.time.point` and continuing to the present,
rather than directly to `present.time.point`, which is what the present progressive needs. Thus,
*I'm having a headache right now/today/at the moment* are all OK, for instance.

As Barrie points out, *today morning* is not grammatical in British or American English;
the idiom there is *this morning* instead.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is grammatical in British Standard English, where what you want is *I've had a headache since this morning.* However, I believe *today morning* is found in Indian English.

Comment: Barrie I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm not saying 'today morning' is wrong. It just isn't found in American or British English.