# "Have got" used with "since"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, have-got

Is it correct to say:

> I have got a bank account since I was 18?

I think that it is wrong because *since* implies something that has happened in the past and is still happening, while *got* is something that has happened and has ended.

My English language teacher says that it is correct.

Comment: Hi, Nero, and welcome to ELU. You might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.  The way to indicate something that started in the past and continues for some time (including the present) is the *present perfect*, "I *have had* a bank account..." Please see [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/) Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Difference between "have had" and "having"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125164/difference-between-have-had-and-having) and please look at the top answer for the following [Which is correct "has died" or "died"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died)

Comment: "I got a new account last year" means I opened a bank account last year. The act of opening an account is fixed in the past. I cannot continue to open a bank account. "I've had (I've got) a new account since last year" means I am still in possession of the account. The act of possession started in the past but *continues* to the present.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *have got* with *since* in this sentence is incorrect for the following reasons:

- *since* denotes time duration from past to present, marked by *since* + fixed past time point. As such, the present perfect tense is appropriate. As in:

*They've lived here since 1990*

*He's been here since the store opened*

- verb phrases using *since* with the above meaning need to express duration (such as action verbs showing duration, e.g.  *live/rain/work/play* or state verbs, e.g. *be/like/love*). The verb ***get*** in its original meaning expresses short, complete actions - and is synonymous in your example above with *obtain, receive*, both of which, as short action verbs, are incompatible with the use of *since* to show duration of state or action.
- the confusion arises from the evolution of the verb ***get*** into the phrasal expression ***have got***, which essentially only has a (n.b.)present tense meaning of ***have / own / possess***. As this refers to the present, it is grammatically incorrect to use as a present perfect with *since* (even if it looks like it is a present perfect with *have+p.p*). If you substitute the example with a synonym, it may help exemplify the error

***I have obtained a bank account since I was 18*** *

- The obvious correction would be to replace get with a verb showing possession over duration, for which the best choice in my opinion would be *have*, as in:

***I have had a bank account since I was 18*** (past to present)

and to finish off, you can state your possession of it now, but without the time expression.

***And I have still got the bank account now***.(present)

Comment: In BrE, you can use have got as a present perfect: We have got many letters in the post since last month. where have got = have gotten in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

- I have got [received] many rude letters in the post recently. [RIGHT, British English]

British, "have got" is the present perfect of *get, to receive,* here. [verb: *get* as *receive*, present perfect in British English, *have got*, meaning *received*]

Now, here's the trick: let's say you want to say in AmE the thing about the date with *since* about a bank account:

> You would not use the present prefect here in American English:

I've gotten a bank account since [year]. The PRESENT PREFECT in American English.

Therefore, if you translate that "have gotten" into British English, you also would not use have got, the PRESENT PERFECT of have:

I've got a bank account since [year].

Because in the bank account, you do not want your present perfect to sound like the present perfect of *get* as in these examples:

> I've got so many calls from them recently. Yes, received, BrE.
>   We've got so much sugar in the past month. Yes, bought, BrE
>   We've gotten so many calls from them recently. Yes, received, AmE
>   We've gotten so much sugar in the past month. Yes, bought, AmE.

So, for the bank account, one must say

> I've had a bank account since last year.

in both varieties of English, 
if one does not want to sound like one is saying "get a bank account", as in *receive, buy, obtain,* etc.

Also, *since* triggers the present perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Your teacher is right that **I have got a bank account since I was 18** is grammatical but it does mean something different from **I have *had* a bank account since I was 18**.

The second sentence means "*I opened a bank account when I was 18 and have had one ever since*" while the first one means "*I was able to open a bank account **because** I was 18*". (This implies that people under 18 cannot have bank accounts).

Your question does not specify the meaning that was intended so it's difficult to say whether the wording was the correct one but, as others have said, "*I have got something*" always refers to an event or a series of events of acquisition in the past but "*I have had something*" refers to posession that continued for a long time and, usually, still continues.

Another thing that makes this a bit complicated is that there are two meanings for the word 'since'. The more common meaning is 'for the time that has passed' and is used in sentences like "*I have lived in this house since 2008*": the other meaning is 'because' or 'as a result of' and is used in sentences like "*You are allowed to rent a car since you have a driving licence*".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *I have got a bank account since I **am** 18*? If it's talking about possession (rather than acquisition), *have got* is equivalent to present tense.

Comment: @PeterShor - It could imply simply obtaining a bank account at some point in time subsequent to turning 18.

Comment: In AmE would you say: I've gotten a bank account since I was 18? I'd say: I have had one since I was 18.

Comment: I have succeeded in getting a bank account because/since I **am** 18.  Or: because/since I **turned** 18.  Not a helpful answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have **had/owned/possesed** a bank account since I was 18?

*Got* is a largely terrible word that should rarely be used.

Comment: The verb  *[have got](http://esl.about.com/cs/beginner/a/beg_havegot.htm)* is perfectly acceptable and very common in BrEng. And you have not answered the question. You have offered alternatives.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me!!

Comment: got is a jewel of the English language.

Answer (score -2):

Both *have* and *have got* may be used to talk about "possession".   *Have got* is not used in formal written English, and is less common in American English than British English.

Notice that sentence structure is in "present perfect"

```
I have got ...
Have you got ... ?
```

and - in British sense- it also denotes "present perfect" action.

So, "I have got a bank account since I was 18" is a correct sentence.

Here is another discussion you may benefit from:
[Have got” — verb form and tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/have-got-verb-form-and-tense)